# AesZipFileEncrypter zipAndEncrypt method adds all folder tree to file

Tags: java, compression, zip, aes

I'm using this method to zip and decrypt a file:
[AesZipFileEncrypter.zipAndEncrypt](http://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/)

This code:

```
AesZipFileEncrypter.zipAndEncrypt(new File("C:\Test\Folder\MyFile.txt"), new File("C:\Test\Folder\MyZip.zip"), password, aesEncrypter);
```

compresses also the folder tree of my file, not just the file. For example:
Adding C:\Test\Folder\MyFile.txt in the created zip file I will find the folders C:\Test\Folder\MyFile.txt also if I would like to have just MyFile.txt in the root folder.
Is it possibile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
    AESEncrypter aesEncrypter = new AESEncrypterBC();
    aesEncrypter.init(password, 0);
    AesZipFileEncrypter ze=new AesZipFileEncrypter(outputfilename, aesEncrypter);
    ze.add(inputfilename,new FileInputStream(inputfilename), password);
    ze.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows (which it looks like you are in) I ran into the same problem and it seems to depend on where the file is relative to your application. To get around it, I copied the input file to the local directory, ziped and encrypted it, then moved the output file back to the where the output file was intended.

```
public static File aesEncrypt(String inFileFullPath, String outFileFullPath, String aesPassword) throws IOException{
    File inFile = new File(inFileFullPath);
    File localInput = new File(inFile.getName());
    Files.copy(inFile, localInput);

    File outFile = new File(outFileFullPath);
    File localOutFile = new File(outFile.getName());

    AESEncrypter aesEncrypter = new AESEncrypterBC();
    aesEncrypter.init(aesPassword, 255);
    AesZipFileEncrypter ze = new AesZipFileEncrypter(localOutFile, aesEncrypter);
    ze.add(localInput, aesPassword);
    ze.close();

    Files.move(localOutFile, outFile);
    localInput.delete();
    return outFile;
}
```

Comment: With my solution you can get around without coping it, however with one file becomes easy, with more files you need to manage a loop

Comment: I used
byte[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
File outputZipFile = new File ("someZipName");
AesZipFileEncrypter ze=new AesZipFileEncrypter(outputZipFile,ENCRIPTER); 
ze.add("name.zip", new ByteArrayInputStream(data), password); ze.close();

but doesn't work, it creates an archive with the name "someZipName" and when I open it you can see the file "name.zip" that generates an error when opening it.

Comment: just for info how to use DECRYPTER after encription, for me fitted unzip() method ;)
see code from:

https://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/source/browse/trunk/winzipaes/src/de/idyl/crypto/zip/AesZipFileEncrypter.java?r=44