# password protected zip file issue

Tags: java, zip, jsch

User upload the file, i need to password protect the file and then zip it put in a storage server which is different from the server where my code is running. So i use AESEncrypter to encrypt the file and jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp to transfer the file to the server.

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploads") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("outputfile.zip");
    AESEncrypter aesEncrypter = new AESEncrypterBC();
    aze=new AesZipFileEncrypter(fos, aesEncrypter);
    aze.add(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream(), "test123");

    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    Session session = ssh.getSession("username", "Servername", 22);

    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword("*****");
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();

    sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    sftpChannel.put(file.getInputStream(), "/storedfiles/outputfile.zip");
}
```

File is getting transferred to the server, but when i download that transferred file and try to open it says "Errors were found opening ".." you cannot extract file.. do you want to fix the problems". Not sure why i am getting this issue, also it creates a file in local server, which line is causing that?

I tried replacing this line

```
aze=new AesZipFileEncrypter(fos, aesEncrypter);
```

with

```
aze=new AesZipFileEncrypter("outputfile.zip", aesEncrypter);
```

but dint work.

Comment: You haven't closed the `AesZipFileEncrypter`, there could be buffered content which  hasn't been written to the file - as demonstrated in [AesZipFileEncrypter zipAndEncrypt method adds all folder tree to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399521/aeszipfileencrypter-zipandencrypt-method-adds-all-folder-tree-to-file)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good catch, yup that solved my one of the issue. My outstanding issue is, file is copied in local server and also it is copied to the remote file server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed the file in remote server, read that in output stream and then password protected, solved my issue.

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploads") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
JSch ssh = new JSch();
Session session = ssh.getSession("username", "Servername", 22);

config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword("*****");
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();

sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
OutputStream os = sftp.put("/storedfiles/outputfile.zip");

AESEncrypter aesEncrypter = new AESEncrypterBC();
aze=new AesZipFileEncrypter(os, aesEncrypter);
aze.add(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream(), "test123");
if(aze != null) {
 aze.close();
}    
}
```